# PowerShell- Get-ADUser Filter Issue

Tags: powershell, filter

New to PowerShell and am having issues with Get-ADUser -Filter.  I believe the issue has to do with the -Filter

```
$TC_TellerID_Array = @()
$TC_TellerID_Array = Import-Csv "C:\Designer.csv"
$ADUsersArray = @()
$ADUsersArray=get-aduser -filter * -Properties * | select Name, SamAccountName, extensionAttribute1, Enabled | where extensionAttribute1 -ne $null
Foreach ($User in $ADUsersArray)
{$TrimmedTeller = ($User.extensionAttribute1).Trim()
Foreach ($TC_TellerID in $TC_TellerID_Array)
{
Get-ADUser -Filter "'$TrimmedTeller' -eq '$TC_TellerID.TellerID'" -Properties * | Select Name,SamAccountName,extensionAttribute1, Enabled
}
}
```

Comment: See thorough description here: [`-Filter` in _Get-ADUser_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps#required-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Those single quotes are forcing a literal string. As @JosefZ pointed out. You would also want to pull your value of TellerID out using a [SubExpression](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) . Try changing your code to look like

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {$TrimmedTeller -eq $($TC_TellerID.TellerID)} -Properties * | Select Name,SamAccountName,extensionAttribute1, Enabled
```